# Simple program with Callable Future never terminates

Tags: concurrency, future, callable

I was playing around with Callable and Future and stumbled upon an issue.

This is a piece of code that never terminates and times out even though the IDE allows 5 seconds to run, and the code does not need more than 3 seconds (It gives a Time Limit Exceeded error): https://ideone.com/NcL0YV

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Ideone obj = new Ideone();
        Future<Integer> res = obj.doCallable();
        System.out.println(res.get());
    }
    public Future<Integer> calculate(Integer input) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        return executor.submit(() -> {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Sleep time in ms = "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
            return input * input;
        });
    }
    public Future<Integer> doCallable() {
        int value = 99;
        try {
            Callable<Future> callable = () -> calculate(value);
            Future<Integer> future = callable.call();
            return future;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a similar piece of code that terminates because I added "System.exit(0)" (which is not advisable): https://ideone.com/HDvl7y

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Ideone obj = new Ideone();
        Future<Integer> res = obj.doCallable();
        System.out.println(res.get());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public Future<Integer> calculate(Integer input) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        return executor.submit(() -> {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Sleep time in ms = "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
            return input * input;
        });
    }
    public Future<Integer> doCallable() {
        int value = 99;
        try {
            Callable<Future> callable = () -> calculate(value);
            Future<Integer> future = callable.call();
            return future;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me understand why do we need System.exit(0) or shutdown() even if callable task is complete (future.get() call is a blocking call).

**EDIT:**
I did all the above to solve the main issue of ever-increasing threads in my application because of the below code snippet. I am not sure how to complete this future automatically after a certain timeout without involving the main thread (which exits right away).

```
@Override
public void publish(@NonNull final String message,
                    @NonNull final String topicArn) throws PublishingException {
    if (!publishAsync(message, topicArn)) {
        throw new PublishingException("Publish attempt failed for the message:"
                + message);
    }
}

private boolean publishAsync(final String message,
                             final String topicArn) {
    Callable<Future> publishCallable = () -> snsClient.publishAsync(topicArn, message);
    try {
        Future<PublishResult> result = publishCallable.call();
        log.debug("Asynchronously published message {} to SNS topic {}.", message, topicArn);
        return !result.isDone() || result.get().getMessageId() != null;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use this executor.shutdown() method @Ritz777

Comment: Hi AKS, I edited the question to include the real problem I am trying to solve, but I have no idea how to solve with the suggestion you provided.

Comment: System.exit() method terminated the whole program and shutdown() method terminated the ThreadPool  service. @Ritz777

Comment: An ExecutorService should be shut down once it is no longer needed to free up system resources and to allow graceful application shutdown. Because the thread in an ExecutorService may be nondaemon thread, they may prevent normal application termination. In other words, your application stays running after completing its main method. You could perform a system.exit(0) call, but it would preferable to allow your thread to complete their current activities. @Ritz777

Answer (score 0):

void shutdown()

Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.

This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTerminationto do that.

Comment: I am aware of shutdown() method, but I am not sure, if it is required everytime an executor service is used. Why do we still need it even though the callable task is completed already?

Comment: Yes it required every time, when  you use ExecutorService. It comparison to used otherwise when didn't use shutdown() method then you program until running mode.